# How do I format Django URL so that AJAX call will get database data that is not dependent on the current page, but from a form value?

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax, url

I have a page that details a post and comments on that post. The pk for this page is the post pk. I want to be able to construct comments using symbols only. I have a series of symbols saved to the database that are all associated with a category class. I have a form on my page that can select one of those categories, but how do I get an AJAX call to load all the symbols in that category? The user will need to be able to chop and change between categories so I wanted to do this with AJAX rather than reload the page each time. So far, all I get are 404, not founds. I want to do this so that I can drag or select symbols to add to comments. I've tried lots of different formats to get the URLs to work (both in `urls.py` and in `main.js`) so I can't list off all the alternatives that I've tried as it's all a bit overwhelming. I've also read through a heap of questions on here and other sites but nothing seems to match what I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Symbols are saved in `media/uploads/symbol_files/`

Symbols have a many-to-many relationship with comments through the model. All this is working fine so I haven't included it below.
At the moment the template is set up to populate a second form with the symbols from the selected category, I'll change this later, I've just got it like this for convenience.

Here's an example of output from the terminal:

```
Not Found: /posts/1/get_symbols/Alphabet
```

Where "Alphabet" is the name of one of the categories.

models.py:

```
class SymbolCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_symbols(self):
        return self.symbol_set.all()
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "SymbolCategory"
        verbose_name_plural = "SymbolCategories"

class Symbol(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/symbol_files')
    category = models.ForeignKey(SymbolCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}-{self.pk}'

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    video_file = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='uploads/video_files', validators = [FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4', 'webm'])])
    thumbnail = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='uploads/thumbnails', validators = [FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png', 'jpg','jpeg'])])
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ForeignKey(PostCategory,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
```

views.py:

```
class DetailPost(View):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        symbol_comments = SymbolComment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-created_on')
        categories = SymbolCategory.objects.all()

        form_comment = CommentForm()
        symbol_get_form = SymbolGetForm()


        context = {
            'object': post,
            'form_comment': form_comment,
            'symbol_comments': symbol_comments,
            'symbol_get_form': symbol_get_form,
            'categories': categories,
        }

        return render(request, 'posts/detail_post.html', context)
    
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form_comment = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form_comment.is_valid():
            symbol_comments = SymbolComment(
                user = self.request.user,
                post = post
            )
            symbol_comments.save()
            
        symbol_comments = SymbolComment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-created_on')
                
        context = {
            'object': post,
            'form_comment': form_comment,
            'symbol_comments': symbol_comments,
        }
        return render(request, 'posts/detail_post.html', context)
      
def get_symbols(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == "POST": # I've tried with GET but it doesn't work either, at the moment it currently has POST but I think this is wrong.
            category_name = request.POST['category_name']
            print(category_name)
            try:
                category = SymbolCategory.objects.filter(id = category_name).first()
                symbols = Symbol.objects.filter(category = category)
            except Exception:
                data['error_message'] = 'error'
                return JsonResponse(data)
            return JsonResponse(list(symbols.values('name', 'image_field')), safe = False)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailPost.as_view(), name='detail-post'),
    path('get_symbols/', get_symbols, name='get-symbols'),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

template:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputStatus">Category</label>
    <select id="select-category" class="form-control-sm custom-select">
      <option selected disabled>Choose a symbol category</option>
      {% for category in categories %}
      <option value="{{category.name}}">{{category.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputStatus">Symbol</label>
      <select id="category-symbol" class="form-control-sm custom-select" name="symbol">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a symbol</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

main.js:

```
$("#select-category").change(function () {
    const categoryName = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({                       
        type: "POST",
        url: `get_symbols/${categoryName}`,
        data: {
            'category_name': categoryName,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {   
            let html_data = '<option value="">---------</option>';
            data.forEach(function (data) {
                html_data += `<option value="${data.id}">${data.name}</option>`
            });
        console.log(data)
        $("#category-symbol").html(html_data); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The url needed to be

`'<int:pk>/'get_symbols'/<int:id>/'`

There were a few other bugs that needed fixing too.